# Outer DIV to wrap and expand upwards along with the inner DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css

Need a little bit help here. Thanks :)

I am struggling with how to make the outer div wrap the inner div and expand upwards along with the inner content editable div.

The inner div should expand from bottom to top and the outer div should wrap it (green color should wrap the red) and expand along with it.

Note: press SHIFT+ENTER in the red div to make it expand upwards.

I have an example in the following codepen

```html
<div style="background-color:green;">
  Test Test
  <div id="example" contenteditable style="background-color:red; position: absolute; bottom: 0px">
    Test Test
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox:

```css
.outer {
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* Some minimal width */
  min-height: 50vh;
}

.inner {
  background: red;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  Test Test
  <div id="example" class="inner" contenteditable>
    Test Test
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Both of them must be absolute and wrappers height must be 100%.

```
<div style="background-color:green;  height: 100%; position: absolute;">
wrapper                                 
  <div id="example" style="border: 1px solid red; position: absolute; bottom: 0;">
    inner
  </div>
</div>
```